# Adding a background image in Calibre

Tags: epub, calibre, css

To get a background image in Calibre, I gather that I need to open a book and right click.  This will expose a menu.  Choosing "Preferences" >> "Styles" opens a GUI to change the background along with a place for more detailed editing of the CSS.  The GUI ends up leaving a white border around the background, which I found I can remove by going to "Page Layout".

What I would really like is if Calibre could recognize that the image itself has a border, but my attempts at using CSS are failing.  The effect I'm looking for is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXWQi.jpg).  The authors are [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Calibre/comments/8deztq/my_custom_calibre_reader_theme/).

Any help would be appreciated.  This is calibre 5.6.0.